# Nginx proxy log duplicate with web server behind the proxy

Tags: logging, nginx

Say I have a Proxy web server (nginx) and a web server (nginx) behind the proxy. Both server enabled `error_log` and `access_log`.

My question is:

Is this necessary to have **2 duplicated Access Logs** at both web server? Is one Access Log sufficient?

They are all the same anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy and Webserver stands different terms. When you are troubleshooting issues, one has to identify whether the issue exists with proxy server or web server. Only by checking the separate logs we will be able to troubleshoot the problem

Consider following scenarios 
 1. Proxy down - webserver running - This can be analyzed using proxy log
 2. Proxy running - webserver down - This can be analyzed using webserver log.

If we have proxy as well as webserver running in same server, then you can make proxy logs and webserver logs point to single file. It will be better solution rather than disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as everything works as expected there is 'no need' for both servers to log.

In case of an error/incident it might help to localize the error (by checking what happened in the past). - Of course you could also disable logging on one server and only enable it in case of a reported failure.

For considering which logs to keep, i doubt that they are exactly the same:

- the error log of the server behind the proxy will contain messages regarding local errors (e.g., error reports of cgi scripts...)
- the error log of the proxy server will contain errors regarding e.g. connection problems to the web server
- depending on your configuration, the access logof the webserver will only show the ip of your prixy server (as this is the client for that server) and the proxy server will show ghe real ips of the clients.